# Meaning of $x^2 \in \mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: notation

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550764/quotient-space-of-s1-is-homeomorphic-to-s1) someone suggested:

"$z\mapsto z^2$"

where both $z$ and $z^2$ are in $\mathbb{S^1}$ (unless I missed something).

Does this mean that they suggested: $z^2 = (z_1^2, z_2^2)$?

If not, what is it?

Comment: It means complex number multiplication.

Comment: Did you see that $z\in\mathbb{C}$ in that question? So $z^2$ is simply the complex multiplication $z \cdot z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z\in S^1 \implies z\in\mathbb C\implies z^2\in\mathbb C;$$$$\\z\in\mathbb C\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies z^2\in\mathbb C^2.$$

Comment: Actually $z \in S^1$ implies $z^2 \in S^1$ as well.

Comment: @principal Well yes of course; that’s consistent with what I said.

Comment: Of course that's consistent ;-). Both is true and truth is consistent!

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments is already pointed out $z^2$ means $z\cdot z$.

You suggestest $(z_1^2,z_2^2)$. That's not how the multiplication in $\mathbb C$ works. It's actually $(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ if $z=(x,y)=x+iy$.